# Combining K-means clustering with Agglomerative clustering

Tags: clustering, k-means

I am trying to identify 6 clusters in a graph of authors. Authors are connected with an edge when they have co-authored on a paper. I have already created a clustering with K-means (6-Means) and with Agglomerative clustering. Now, I want to combine these two clustering approaches in order to get more accurate clusters.
I am able to find corresponding clusters, but I have no clue on how to decide to which cluster an author belongs when the algorithms do not agree.

Possibly I could use some form of a linear combination, but I do not know how to apply this properly. Other methods might be possible, but I am not sure on that.

Comment: The bozo solution might be to run one algorithm then create an additional feature "cluster_label" and feed it into the next algorithm.  You could then scale the "cluster_label" feature up or down until you get the result you want.  Possibly experiment with the ordering of the two.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_clustering

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a graph of co-authors, it might make more sense to frame the problem at [spectral clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering) which is graph based.

Then, you can apply something like [consensus clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_clustering) to combine the clusters.